# Platform specific code for shared watchOS/iOS classes in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, watchos, code-sharing

I am currently building an iOS app with a watchOS app extension. I have certain classes that are shared between both apps, and they are largely identical on both platforms, but with certain variations. I am wondering how this is best implemented. Right now I use the following:

```
#if os(watchOS)
private var watchOSOnlyProperty: Any?
#endif
```

or

```
#if os(iOS)
func iOSOnlyMethod() {
    ...
}
#endif
```

While this works, it gives several problems since XCode seems to be pretty confused about this. Indentation, autocompletion and the list of methods are all a bit off when using this syntax.

What is the proper way to do this? How can you add iOS/watchOS-specific properties & methods to shared classes in Swift?

Comment: That is the proper way

Comment: Hm... this produces so many problems for me in XCode that I would consider it not really viable, though. For example, autocompletion has pretty much stopped working completely for me for classes that use this. Any alternatives?

Comment: Create different source files for the different targets.  This should work though.  Try deleting your derived data

Comment: didn't help unfortunately :/ neither in XCode 8 nor XCode 9 beta 4. I did notice the problem only occurs inside `#if os(watchOS)` blocks, `#if os(iOS)` seems unaffected.

Answer (score 2):

**Code separation**

There are two ways to separate code

- Use `#if os(...)` like you suggested.
- Use separate files for the
  different targets.

**Auto completion**

Xcode will only autocomplete code for your current selected target.
[image: Xcode target selector]

If you want autocompletion for code inside `#if os(watchOS)` blocks then you need to change your current target (via the toolbar) to the wathOS target.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a C preprocessor flag in the Build Settings for the Watch app target.

```
-DWATCHOS
```

Then

```
#ifdef WATCHOS
// watchOS code here
#else
// iOS code here
#endif
```

will work.